# What is the meaning of “PSP”?

Tags: meaning, acronyms

This Daily Mail article ([Was French patrol boat at fault for Channel migrant drownings?](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-12401039/amp/Was-French-patrol-boat-fault-Channel-migrant-drownings-MPs-ask-dinghy-escorted-British-waters-tragedy-saw-six-die.html)) refers to both PSP Pluvier and PSP Cormoran.

What does that term mean?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it about a french abbreviation.  Unrelated to the English language.

Comment: Remember to scrub your brain and eyeballs after reading.

Comment: Must be a helluva tabloid.

Answer (score 2):

"Patrouilleur de service public" (French for "public service patrol boat").  See [this article](https://www.defense.gouv.fr/operations/actualites/baltique-13-jours-au-sein-force-alliee-psp-pluvier) (in French) from the French defence ministry about the vessel in question.

Comment: Could you perhaps give a literal translation?